# SQL DISTINCT query on Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table like this:

```
Artist   Image   Title

Smith    2       Country
Smith    5       Town
Doyle    21      Cat
Lawlor   24      Ball
Jones    8       Cheese
Jones    12      Bread
Jones    15      Butter
```

And I want to set up  a DISTINCT Query to return the Artist once - doesn't matter which of the records are returned. This is what I'm looking for:

```
Artist   Image   Title
Smith    2       Country
Doyle    21      Cat
Lawlor   24      Ball
Jones    8       Cheese
```

I am using ASP on a MS Access database.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access has `FIRST`and `LAST` aggregates which r[eturn the first or last record as it was entered in chronological order](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=60565)

```
SELECT Artist, FIRST(Image) AS Image, FIRST(Title) AS Title
FROM table
GROUP BY Artist
```

Comment: Actually, it's a bit more complicated than data entered chronological order; rather it's based on clustered index order. Clustered index is based on the table's `PRIMARY KEY`; if there is no `PRIMARY KEY` it is known to use a `UNIQUE` constraint but there is more than one to choose no one know which one it will choose. The clustered index is rebuilt when the file is compacted and subsequently inserted rows will be considered in chronological order. In other words, `FIRST` and `LAST` should be considered arbitrary.

Comment: @onedaywhen - Thanks for the clarification. Is it guaranteed that if used for multiple columns they will be from the same row at all times?

Comment: Actually, First() and Last() are based on the ORDER BY. If you don't provide an ORDER BY, it may be correct that it will be based on clustered index order, but I wouldn't bet on it. Frankly, I don't see the point of including columns where you're basically choosing at random what you want to display in those columns.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton, Could you give an example of how FIRST and LAST are affected by ORDER BY? I've never seen an explanation of how that's possible. In a GROUP BY query only the grouped columns are permitted in the ORDER BY. FIRST and LAST return values for *each* group but AFAIK there is no way to specify the order *within* each group in an ORDER BY clause. Therefore it seems to me that the results must be arbitrary with or without an ORDER BY. What am I missing?

Comment: Martin, thanks a lot for your response. My head was sore from banging things inside and outside of it, trying to sort this one out, so your time is very much appreciated. I haven't sorted out the order by element yet, but that's a minor issue.

Comment: @dportas: you're right, there is no way to sort outside the GROUP BY, and using a sorted subquery doesn't make a difference. I'm no defender of First/Last -- I have never used them because I don't know what they mean, other than choosing a random value to display. I can't recall the last time I needed random data, so it's not something I use. The very fact that the result is not meaningful is why I would not use it, moreso than the reliability of the results.