# What is MySQL equivalent of MS Access LAST()?

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I have no idea what the following query means as I do not have any exposure to MS Access. I need to convert it into MySQL and I can't figure out what does the LAST() does

```
SELECT 
    Containers.Container_No, 
    Max(Containers.LastOfContainer_Date), 
    Max(Containers.LastOfContainer_Time), 
    Last(Containers.LastOfETD), 
    Last(Containers.LastOfContainer_Status), 
    Last(Containers.LastOfPickup_From), 
    Last(Containers.LastOfPickup_To), 
    Last(Containers.LastOfConsignee_Name), 
    Last(Containers.LastOfContract_No), 
    Last(Containers.LastOfSeaLNo) 
FROM 
    Containers 
WHERE 
    Containers.Customer_Name = 'value here"
AND  
    Containers.LastOfContainer_Date >='Date here' 
AND 
    Containers.LastOfContainer_Date <= 'Date here' 
GROUP BY 
    Containers.Container_No
```

Can some one explain me what does this LAST() actually do?
**UPDATE**
It seems the query can be changed to following:

```
SELECT
        Containers.Container_No,
        Max(Containers.LastOfContainer_Date),
        Max(Containers.LastOfContainer_Time),
        Containers.LastOfETD,
        Containers.LastOfContainer_Status,
        Containers.LastOfPickup_From,
        Containers.LastOfPickup_To,
        Containers.LastOfConsignee_Name,
        Containers.LastOfContract_No,
        Containers.LastOfSeaLNo
    FROM
        Containers
    WHERE
        Containers.Customer_Name = '".$customername."'
    AND
        Containers.LastOfContainer_Date >='".$fromdate."'
    AND
        Containers.LastOfContainer_Date <= '".$todate."'
    GROUP BY
        Containers.Container_No
    order by
        Containers.LastOfETD,
        Containers.LastOfContainer_Status,
        Containers.LastOfPickup_From,
        Containers.LastOfPickup_To,
        Containers.LastOfConsignee_Name,
        Containers.LastOfContract_No,
        Containers.LastOfSeaLNo
```

Comment: [The comment trail on my answer here might help (or not!)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407480/sql-distinct-query-on-multiple-columns/5407493#5407493)

Comment: [And here's the Microsoft page on the `Last()` function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/first-last-functions-HP001032232.aspx)

Comment: I the `Container_No` unique across the table or is there any other id field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Last function returns the last value on a given query, for instance I assume that in the query you are using it would return the data of the last transaction made by that certain customer, 
for instance lets say Mike Jagger bought 2things today, he will have 2 transactions with the same date, if you use the last function you would get the latest information that was inserted.

```
ID    | Date |   Product
1    12/12/2011   socks
2     12/12/2011   shirt

select  last(product)
from buys;

it would output : shirt
```

BTW to emulate this behavior you might want to use

```
ORDER BY product DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I have changed the query and updated the question can you have a look at it

Comment: ok, the latter doesn't have the Last() function though, I thought your question was what does that function does.

Comment: yes I wanted to know what actually it does, read other comments and the sql you have given helped me. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/last.php), "*The **Last** function returns the last value from the result set of a query.*"

You might have to do some kind of `ORDER BY x DESC LIMIT 1`.