# How to use Last() of SQL server in Vb.net

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vb.net

Last() is used to retrieve the last record of a column in a table in SQL. And the query "select Last(id) from project", id=column name and project is the table name, is working fine. But when i used this query in VB.net while trying to fetch the last record of a column in a table from the database, it is not recognised. it is Is there any alternative to perform this action?? Its a huge code. this is the part of the code where i get the error:

```
str = "select Last(id) from details"
 cmd = New SqlCommand(str, con)  //con is the connection which works fine
 adapt = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd) // error here "Last() is not inbuilt function"
 adapt.Fill(ds) 
 i = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(1)
 i = i + 1
```

Comment: Adding the code that you use to call this query in VB.NET could be very useful here

Comment: Guys, I got it.. i put the code inside Try Catch exception. it works. Try
                str = "select Last(id) from details"
                cmd = New SqlCommand(str, con)
                adapt = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                adapt.Fill(ds)
                i = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(1)
                i = i + 1
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

Comment: Really? I fail to see how adding a try/catch could make Last (an inexistant native function on Sql Server) works. You are hiding a bug inside an empty try/catch....

Comment: @James: what do you want to do with the new value of `i` (`i + 1`) ?

Comment: "Last" as ordered by what? The access behaviour for that query wouldn't be well defined [from the comments on my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5407493/73226)